# Python for renaming XML elements

Tags: python, xml

I have a XML file where I want to edit or rename elements and save the file. What is the best way to do it. The XML file is given below

```
<breakfast_menu>
<food>
    <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$5.95</price>
    <description>two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
    <calories>650</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$7.95</price>
    <description>light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
    <calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$8.95</price>
    <description>light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
    <calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>French Toast</name>
    <price>$4.50</price>
    <description>thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
    <calories>600</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
    <price>$6.95</price>
    <description>two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
    <calories>950</calories>
</food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

How can I change "description" to "details"?

Answer (score 13):

I'm suggesting you to use [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse your XML document.

This is the simple and the best library to deal with XML docs in python.

Here is an example code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xmlParser
xmlDoc = xmlParser.parse('path to your xml doc')
rootElement = xmlDoc.getroot()

for element in rootElement.iter('description'):
    element.tag = 'details'

# Saving the xml
xmlDoc.write('path to your new xml doc')
```

Comment: How do I repair malformed XML where the opening tag and closing do not match. like in the XML below

Answer (score 0):

If your xml will always stay this simple, you could use regular expressions:

```
import re
xml = """
<breakfast_menu>
...
</breakfast_menu>
"""
regex = re.compile('<description>(.*)</description>')
xml = regex.sub(r'<details>\1</details>',xml)
```

Comment: How do I repair malformed XML where the opening tag and closing do not match.

Comment: You could break down the regular expression into two pieces for the opening and closing tag: `opening = re.compile('<description>')` `closing = re.compile('</description>')`. This would substitute the opening tag even if there is no closing tag, but the malformed XML would not be automatically repaired.
In general it is not a good idea to handle non-regular markup with regular expressions. But regular expressions are great and very efficient, if you are totally sure, that your input will always follow certain rules.

Answer (score -2):

Well you have two options. If the xml is small, a plain string replacement would do. If the xml is very big then I would advise applying a xsl transformation.

Comment: This just part of a longer file.How do I do xsl transformation using python